# Is there any effective difference between those two functions?

Tags: python, difference

I was trying to understand what is the effective difference between those two pieces of code. They are both written for an assignment I got at school, but only the first one works as it should. I've been unable to understand what goes wrong in the second one so I'd be fantastically grateful if someone could shine some light on this problem.

First code:

```
def classify(self, obj):
    if sum([c[0].classify(obj)*c[1] for c in self.classifiers]) >0:
        return 1
    else: return -1

def update_weights(self, best_error, best_classifier):
    w=self.data_weights
    for index in range(len(self.data_weights)):
        if self.standard.classify(self.data[index])==best_classifier.classify(self.data[index]):
            s=-1
        else: s=1
        self.data_weights[index] = self.data_weights[index]*math.exp(s*error_to_alpha(best_error))
```

Second code:

```
def classify(self, obj):
    score = 0
    for c, alpha in self.classifiers:
        score += alpha * c.classify(obj)
    if score > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

def update_weights(self, best_error, best_classifier):
    alpha = error_to_alpha(best_error)
    for d, w in zip(self.data, self.data_weights):
        if self.standard.classify(d) == best_classifier.classify(d):
            w *= w * math.exp(alpha)
        else:
            w *= w * math.exp(-1.0*alpha)
```

Comment: A brief description of what they're supposed to do and how the one isn't working would help a lot

Comment: Do both classify functions give the same results? If not, fix that first.

Comment: "My code isn't working" is not a valid type of question. You also have provided no explanation for *what* is not working, you have not provided a sample input and expected output, you have not provided any errors or stack trace. What kind of responses are you expecting exactly? We do not have many clairvoyants here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second doesn't modify the weights.

in the first you explicitly modify the weights array with the line

```
self.data_weights[index] = ...
```

but in the second you are only modifying `w`:

```
w *= ...
```

(and you have an extra factor of w).  in the second case, w is a variable that is initialised from `data_weights`, but it is a new variable.  it is not the same thing as the array entry, and changing its value does not change the array itself.

so when you later go to look at `data_weights` in the second case, it will not have been updated.